# Pebble App Crashed

Tags: pebble-watch, cloudpebble, pebble-js

Does anybody know what's happening with my pebble app?

```
var UI = require('ui');
var Vector2 = require('vector2');

var wind = new UI.Window({ fullscreen: true });
var width = 144;
var height = 168;

var splashscreen = new UI.Image({
  position: new Vector2(0, 0),
  size: new Vector2(width, height),
  image: 'images/splash.png'
});

wind.add(splashscreen);
wind.show();
```

I don't know why, but I am receiving the "app crashed" message.

Thanks

Comment: Could you reproduce the relevant part of the error message?

Comment: Thanks. I deleted the project and created a new one. Simply worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and found nothing wrong. It might have been the loaded image got corrupted when uploading it the first time. It also could have been an issue with the test watch that had a lot of items loaded and caused the crash.

Either way, it appears you were able to resolve the issue by recreating the app in a new project. I wish we had the error message to be able to diagnose if the issue was local or might affect others and require adjustments to be made to prevent this from happening in the future.